# Can I transfer my Overwatch account stats/skins from Xbox to PS4?

Tags: overwatch

I currently play on Xbox one but I am looking to trade my Xbox for a Playstation 4, so that I can play with more of my friends. I know I've read about it not being possible to link accounts through PS4 and PC, but that's not
really what I'm looking for.

Is it possible to link my account between the two consoles? Like being able to get my level and comp rating. Also, is it possible for me to transfer skins? I have a lot of legendaries and really don't want to lose them.

Answer (score 1):

For skins, [this site](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/bnet/topic/20744165724) states no. It's specific to PS4 and PC, but I suspect Xbox is going to fall in that category.

Additionally, as of 19 Apr, [this thread](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20754355434) discusses that there are no cross-console options.